# Best way to store much data in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

As you can see on the picture, I've a big table with all my products of my virtual webshop. This view is the admin panel. All the data you can see in the input field are fetched with a select statement when the page loads.

**What I want to realise**: When someone edits the value of an input field at different places in the table, this specific data should be updated in my database.

What is the best way to realise this? Do I need to work with multi-dimensional arrays? Fetch all the data of that input field and overwrite all my database with update statement?

[image]

Comment: Your row has an id.  Presumably that id is associated with an id in the database.  If you only change one field for a "record", that's really the only thing you need to update.  But you could pass the whole record information in and just update it all.  Entirely up to you.  This question is too broad.

Comment: Perfect that's what i needed to know. I was afraid that my site gonna be slow if i update all my table for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the id of the row in the edit form. So you can send that with the changed values to the backend. Now you can update only that changed row in the database.

Comment: Okey? And how can i know if a row is edited? Do i need to compare each row in my table with the data in, my database, and if it is different, that pass the id?

Comment: okey this depends on the application you build. to edit you have some kind of formular? there you can path the id via hidden field or something than you can use 'update' sql query. like taplar said you can patch every information of that row.

Comment: Can i use session variable instead of hidden input field?

Comment: sure but that all depends on you application structure